# How/When does Django calculate the ForeignKey object

Tags: django, django-models

I have a models class `class A(models.Model): user = models.ForeignKey(User)`

Now if I do a `a = A.objects.get(pk = something_existing); print a.__dict__`, `user` is not in `__dict__`. `a.user` however doesnot give an attribute error.

So when is the actual user being calculated? I looked in `django.db.models.base.Model` and `django.db.models.base.ModelBase` classes and they do not override `__getattr__`, (which I guessed might be being done), so where is this calculated/populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django [relation fields](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/related.py) are implemented as [descriptors](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm).

Comment: Ok, but I dont see a `__get__` and family in `models.Model` or metaclass, so how is this a descriptor?

Comment: The model is not a descriptor, the fields are.

Comment: To be clear, related fields (ForeignKey, ManyToMany, etc) are implemented as descriptors (look in db/models/fields/related.py). Most fields (CharField, IntegerField) do not use descriptors.

Comment: Edited the answer to be more accurate.